# Проверить матрицу на симметричность относительно главной оси

Tags: pascal

Помогите, пожалуйста. Не знаю как проверить эту матрицу на симметричность относительно главной оси.

```
const n=6; m=6;
    var a:array[1..n,1..m] of integer;
        i,j:integer;
    begin
     writeln('matrix:');
     for i:=1 to n do 
     begin
      for j:=1 to m do 
      begin
       A[i,j]:=random(2);
       write(A[i,j]:2);
      end;
      writeln;
     end;
    end.
```

пробовал в конце циклом так оно ересь пишет:

```
for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to m do
  if a[i,j]<>a[j,i] then
  writeln ('матрица не симметрична ')
  else writeln ('матрица симметрична');
```

Comment: а что смотреть-то? Тут и нет ничего. Заполнение матрицы рандомными числами? У вас вроде бы в вопросе другая задача фигурирует

Comment: Да вот, НЕ ЗНАЮ как её проверить на симметричность/

Answer (score 1):

Главное в программировании, уметь разбивать задачи на части

```
// Проверяем на квадратность
Symmetrical := (m = n);

// Проверяем на симметричность
if Symmetrical then
for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to m do // тут можно написать for j:=i+1 to m do
    Symmetrical := Symmetrical and (a[i,j] = a[j,i]);

// Выводим результат
if Symmetrical then
  writeln ('матрица симметрична')
else
  writeln ('матрица не симметрична');
```

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм примерно таков:

1. Проверяете матрицу на квадратность. Если она не квадратна, то и не симметрична
2. Если квадратна, то бегаете по всем ячейкам матрицы, что лежат над главной диагональю. Сравниваете их с соответствующими эдементами под главной диагональню. Например в матрице 3*3 элемент M[1,3] сравниваете с элементом M[3,1], элемент M[1,2] сравниваете с элементом M[2,1] и так далее. 
   Маленькая подсказка: элемент M[i, j] лежит над главной диагональю,  если i > j
3. Если ячейки равны, переходите к следующей. Если хотя бы одна пара ячеек не равна между собой, матрица симметрична. В противном случае симметрична.

Код извините писать не буду, его несложно воспроизвести из алгоритма

Comment: да не за что. Ваш код кстати вроде бы вполне правильный. Только вот делает в два с лишним раза больше сравнений, чем нужно